# Regex string required to differentiate between 'Stock' and 'Stocktaking'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have Javascript code which finds a particular word within a paragraph. I have two words 'Stock' and 'Stocktaking', which are required to be searched within a paragraph. However, if only Stocktaking is there in the paragraph it searches and shows 'Stock' and not stocktaking as a whole help.

[image]

Comment: Use word boundaries ~ `/\bstock\b/i`

Comment: also show what you have tried so far & logic used.

Comment: "I have Javascript code which finds a particular word within a paragraph." - showing this code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

`\b(Stock|Stocktaking)\b/i`

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(stock|stocktaking)`- This will match literal word `stock` or `stocktaking`.
- `i` -  `i` flag makes it insensitive of case so it will match both upper and lower case.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gDG07a/1)

In case you want to read more about word boundary you should go through this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions